# Application Insights support multi environment for java

Tags: java, azure, azure-application-insights

We develop a web app using Java as back-end with NetBeans. I want to read InstrumentationKey from the environment (like Dev,Prod,Stage) instead of from the XML file. I read [enter link description here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/#ikey) but I still don't know where to start. Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/#dynamic-ikey and the Javadoc of the Classes com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient & com.microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetry.TelemetryContext in http://dl.windowsazure.com/applicationinsights/javadoc/. I recommend you refer to this office document about how to use application insight using Java: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-java-get-started/

To avoid mixing up telemetry from development, test and production environments,you can change the instrumentation keys depending on the environment.
Instead of getting the instrumentation key from the configuration XML file, you can set it in your code. Set the key in an initialization method.

Java Sample code:

```
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetry.TelemetryContext;

TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient();
TelemetryContext context = client.getContext();

// Change instrumentationKey
// Step #1: Get OS Environment Variable

String env = System.getenv("APP_INSIGHTS_ENV");

// Step #2: Get Key from Properties file
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(...);
String myKey = props.getProperty(env);
Context.setInstrumentationKey(myKey);
```

Also, you can refer to this similar scenario using C#:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/07/application-insights-support-for-multiple-environments-stamps-and-app-versions.aspx

Best Regards.

Comment: Where did u set this code? I am using spring boot, I set the key in the Main class, not working.

Comment: @RonaldRandon Could you create a new SO thread for your issue and code?